# Can I increase the range of armature frame ghosting?

Tags: animation, armature

When animating an armature for some kind of loop (like a walk cycle), I find the ghost feature to be very helpful. However, I can't seem to set the *range* higher than **30**, nor the *step* higher than **20**.

Currently I'm working on an animation cycle that completes in 80 frames, and I'd like to set the range to 40 and step to 40, so I can mirror the various poses the cycle goes through, without cluttering up the view with other states.

But as I mentioned above, the settings won't go over 30/20. Is this some known (maybe purposeful) limitation? Is there a workaround?